# Homestead 5, Xdebug, PHP 7, and PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug, homestead

I am trying to use Xdebug in PhpStorm with a Homestead 5.0 Vagrant box using PHP 7.0. I am using macOS Sierra.

My problem:

PhpStorm can not find the Xdebug debugger in the PHP interpreters dialog box. It says "Debugger: Not installed".

[image]

Things I have done:

In /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d, my 20-xdebug.ini has the following code:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 250
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
```

I have restarted the php7.0-fpm using `sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`.

I have read from other community forums that Xdebug comes installed on Homestead 5. However, when I run `php -m | grep xdebug` the xdebug extension is not listed. Yet, when I run `phpinfo()` xdebug is listed.

I have ensured that my IDE is using port 9000, my IDE key is 'vagrant' in both places.

Thank you for the help!

Additional screenshots:
[image]

Comment: make sure you are using the php interpreter you think you are.  remember, apache/httpd uses a completely different one to cli.  does `phpinfo()` confirm the settings youre expecting?

Comment: I have used `/usr/bin/php -m` to verify that xdebug is not listed.

Comment: yes, hence the problem. Youre checking the cli install of php, not the php module that apache is using.  There will be another php.ini file somewhere.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I have run `phpinfo()` and found that Xdebug version 2.4.0 is installed. Yet the PhpStorm interpreter is still not detecting it.

Comment: Just get `phpinfo()` output via browser -- the top table will list the config files used. 100% that it will be different one to the one you see on your screenshot (which is for CLI environment). PHP Interpreters work in CLI environment -- which could be (it is in your case) different to what your Apache/nginx/etc is using. If you will be debugging via browser (web pages) then you should not look at what PHP Interpreter shows

Comment: The additional .ini files section shows the 20-xdebug.ini file that I listed in the question. Why would PhpStorm not be detecting the debugger?

Comment: Where does it show that? I do not see it on screenshot you have provided so far.

Comment: I have added the additional screen shot.

Comment: **You still missing the point:** your PHP that executed by web server (*extremely likely*) uses DIFFERENT set of config files than the one which used in CLI environment. PHP Interpreters uses CLI environment. You can run `php -i` and check for the config files it uses there.

Comment: If you want to check what PHP configs web server uses -- use `Run | Web Server Debug Validation` (a Deployment entry most likely will be required -- I'm not using it myself so not sure on exact procedure/requirements).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124324/discussion-between-matthew-and-lazyone).

Comment: *"your PHP that executed by web server (extremely likely) uses DIFFERENT set of config files than the one which used in CLI environment."*

What is the reason for that madness, and how do I set the php config for the CLI environment??

When I go to *Run | Web Server Debug Validation* it recognises the Debugger extension (it shows *Xdebug 2.5.4*), but in the PHP interpreters dialog box it says "Debugger: Not installed", exactly as per Matthew's screenshot.

Comment: I'm having the same problems as you, Matthew, and after hours of frustrated searching I've finally come across this page, but unfortunately I'm not following what's been said here. (It's unfortunate you moved the discussion to chat which is now a dead-link).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get XDebug working a few weeks ago with the latest version of Homestead as of writing this on 2017-05-13. PhpStorm will not detect my XDebug extension in the GUI. That was where the break-down was occurring in my attempts to get things up and running after a fresh install of Homestead was created.

However, after installing XDebug in my VM, setting up the xdebug php extension file, and configuring everything back to how it would have normally functioned, it worked on my first (re)attempt at debugging.

This [guide](http://blog.elenakolevska.com/debugging-laravel-on-homestead/) is how I originally learned how to set up the configurations in PhpStorm. It does not discuss setting an ide-key and some other small things, but most of which are easily discoverable.

Comment: If by any chance you have the time and inclination, It'd be great if you could be a bit more explicit about *what you actually did* to get this to work. I have already done everything in that guide and have exactly the same problem as you describe. PhpStorm just refuses to detect xdebug in the interpreters dialog box.

Comment: My PhpStorm setup still does not detect Xdebug will when performing a debug with the appropriate configuration. However the code will stop on break points properly. I will provide a detailed explanation later this evening for future visitors, but for now have you attempted running the debugger despite the GUI not showing that Xdebug was detected? If not, I'd give it a go.

Comment: https://blog.42mate.com/using-xdebug-with-vagrant-and-phpstorm/

Here's one that is very similar.